# Who's that book by? vs. Whom's that book by?

Tags: usage, interrogatives

> Who's that book by? vs. Whom's that book by?

Which one is more spoken by native English speakers?

Which one is more written by native English writers?

In terms of grammar, in the past, only 'whom' was accepted as a correct form — by whom(objective case of 'who')

Comment: I was about to write a detailed Answer, when I noticed that 635 Questions on ELL contain "who or whom" - https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=who+or+whom
Please, how many, if not specifically which of those went into your research?

Comment: A proper rearrangement would be, "That book is by whom?" (correct use of object, with him replaceable for whom) Leading to a response of, "That book is by him."

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Who's that book by?

is 100% natural and common.

> Whom's that book by?

I've never heard it, and it sounds terrible to me, though I suppose technically the grammar is good.

> Whom is that book by?

Without the contraction, it sounds OK, but is not common at all. It sounds overly formal or stuffy.

Comment: Or "By whom is that book?" (If the test writer want you to use whom, they also probably don't want to end in a preposition)

Comment: @James K, You agree with that 'by who' is not acceptable?

Comment: @BEBYGONES It's a question of **acceptable to whom**.  Except in certain circles, the use of **whom** in the English language is dying. It's now idiomatic, if not actually correct, to follow a preposition with *who*.  Sadly!

Comment: @RonaldSole I'm sad to hear that 'whom' is dying and thanks for your helpful comment. But I still think if preposition and its object are used sticking together, then objective case is more common and idiomatic than subjective case.

Comment: @BEBYGONES no one person gets to decide what's "common and idiomatic" - that can only be *observed*

Comment: @AakashM   Google **"whom" disappearing from English** to get a better idea of how many sites deal with the decline of **whom**.

Comment: @BEBYGONES google ngrams does show "by whom" as more common than "by who" even in the fiction corpus (which is likely to be more idiomatic than non-fiction) although the gap has closed enormously over the past century. I tried a similar comparison for "who is it by", "who's it by" and "whom is it by", but the latter had too few hits to appear https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=by+who%2Cby+whom&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=27&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cby%20who%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cby%20whom%3B%2Cc0

Comment: that is to say, immediately after a preposition the oblique form is still more common even in fiction, but when not immediately after the preposition and before the verb, the subjective form is universal

Comment: It's a good thing that it is disappearing! You don't want the language to go the opposite direction, with 5 different, overlapping words for "the" depending on the noun's gender and case...

Comment: When _whom_ is used, it never leaves a preposition stranded.

Comment: Contracted or not, "Whom is that book by?" should not sound OK. Much more than merely "not common at all, overly formal or stuffy" it's simply wrong. In that context we always need "By whom…", we should never use "Whom by" and no, "Whom is that book by?" doesn't change anything.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Nonsense.  Unlike "whom" in the oblique which is a feature of English which is becoming increasingly archaic, the "rule" that a preposition cannot be separated from its object is something intentionally imported from Latin that never really caught on.  They are unrelated except in the fact that they are both pet peeves of the most pedantic sort of prescriptivists.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin What do you mean by "oblique"?

Comment: Whenever there is a preposition (in this case, _by_), it should be _whom_ because it is objective case. (Though usage obviously tends to differ).

Comment: @BEBYGONES "oblique" is a term that can be used to refer to all case forms other than the nominative/subjective case. In English specifically, it also usually excludes genitive/possessive case forms and is sometimes used rather than accusative/objective to highlight that those forms are also used in places other languages might use a dative (and historically it developed from a merger of the accusative and dative cases)

Comment: @BEBYGONES Does Tristan clear that up? I didn't use "oblique."

Comment: @Sriotchilism O'Zaic I don't think I said that, thanks. Didn't I say always "By whom…" never "Whom by"? I thought that was about order, not separation. What am I missing?

Comment: @SriotchilismO'Zaic: if your claim is that the accusative declination of 'who' is now archaic, then don't use 'whom' at all.  The accusative takes an object, which makes it ineligible to be the subject of a sentence.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I spoke loosely to conserve space, fair enough. But the core point is true the "rule" that a preposition must precede it's object (preposition stranding) is not one based in logic. It is a import from Latin which still remains in the minority. Whom in the oblique as a rule is a native rule that has been falling out of favor. There is nothing illogical about "Whom is the book by" and at a time when use of whom was more widespread it would have been perfectly common. Both are markers of prestige dialects but do not share any logical relationship.

Comment: @nomen I'm not sure what you are saying.  I use whom all the time, because it's how I speak.  It's still archaic and likely to disappear completely, and that's fine.

Comment: @SriotchilismO'Zaic: I'm talking about your "correction" of another poster, who said that " "Whom is that book by?" should not sound OK. "  He is correct.  In that sentence, the 'whom' is the subject of the sentence.  Wrong declension for the subject.

Comment: @nomen Consider the sentence, "Who is going to the picnic?" Certainly "who" is the subject, and I can answer the question by replacing "who" with another subject: "I am going to the picnic." Now let's try that with "Who is that book by?" Shall I answer, "I am that book by"? No, because the subject of *that* question is "that book". Likewise, if I ask, "Where is that book?" the subject is again "that book" and not "where".

Comment: The preposition at the end is a deal breaker for me.  It causes me to ask the question "By what?"  "By the duck?"  "By the aircraft carrier?"  Nope, I can't do it.  "Who wrote that?" or "Who wrote that book?" is more clear and natural.

Comment: @DavidK: Your assertion that you can just replace a subject by another subject is incorrect.  Among other things, they must have the same number, has to agree with the verb, etc etc.

Comment: @nomen I didn't say one could swap subjects willy-nilly. Note that I had to change the verb from "is" to "am" in order to replace "who" by "I". But whoever the "who" is in the original question, I am pretty sure they are not a book written by, which is what they would be if they were the subject of that question.

Comment: I do not claim mine is the most useful voice here and please, everyone, can you respect the fact there are at least 635 previous Questions on SE ELL containing "who or whom" ( ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=who+or+whom)

Is it unreasonable to ask people Commenting here how many, if not specifically which of those they've read?

I guess there's no specific rule against trying to reinvent the wheel and is that a reason to try it?

Answer (score 16):

The simplest way to ask that question is:

> Who wrote that book?

The original "Who's that book by?" is a clunky, unnatural construction.  You've got the who/whom thing going on as well as the often maligned "ending a sentence with a preposition."

"Who wrote that book?" is simple and direct.  It is clear and natural.  It's the way I (as a native English speaking person) would say it.

Comment: to me it sounds natural enough with a pronoun (e.g. "who's it by"). If my friend was talking about a book they were reading, and I wanted to find out its author, this would seem more natural to me than saying "who wrote it". Otoh, if I were pointing at a book in a shop or library and asking about its author I agree that "who wrote that book" is more natural

Comment: "Who wrote that book?" transforms to "He wrote that book." quite naturally.  And the ending on a preposition is also a problem because a preposition is a pre-position.  It expects a position.  And further "Who's that book by?" (adding a position) naturally gets strange as "Who's that book by the duck?"  "Who wrote that?" (dropping the object book as implied) is also valid and natural.  "Who's wrote that?" or "Who is wrote that?" would cause me to cringe if heard in conversation if not done to intentionally sound wrong. (which I intentionally do sometimes)

Comment: -1: I (native UK English speaker) would always use "Who's that book by?" and it would be perfectly understood by everyone I know. I would likely never use "Whom's that book by?" unless I was trying to sound deliberately over-correct.

Comment: @Tristan Agreed, "Who's it by" sounds fine. If someone wants to be more formal, "By whom?" would be the construction that avoids ending a sentence in a preposition and correctly uses the objective rather than subjective form of the author.

Answer (score 10):

My school (in rural Australia) never once even mentioned that there were times that "whom" would be a better choice of words, but as I started to encounter the word in the wild I figured out a fairly practical test for use in my own writing: replace "who" with "he" and "whom" with "him" to form a sentence that looks like an answer, and see which version of the answer makes sense.

- "*Who* wrote the book?" => "*He* wrote the book."
- "*Whom* wrote the book?" => "*Him* wrote the book."
- "By *who* was the book written?" => "By *he* was the book written." (or "By *he* the book was written.")
- "By *whom* was the book written?" => "By *him* was the book written." (or "By *him* the book was written")

The second and third of those examples both stand out as wrong to me.

The interesting thing about this question is that both "He's that book by" and "Him's that book by" *both* seem wrong. If I found myself writing or speaking in the sort of situation where I thought my audience would take note of "who" vs "whom" and needed to ask the question I'd very likely rephrase it to one of my "good" examples from above.

It's also my experience that a relatively small portion of my audience will even notice a "who" that should've been a "whom", and a tiny subset of those will object to it. It's probably more common to object to a "whom" that should've been a "who" than the reverse. In that light, "Who's that book by" is your best bet. If in doubt, leave it out!

Comment: Note that the awkwardness of "him's that book by" is primarily one of word order - change it to "that book is by him", and it sounds natural. That suggests "that book is by whom" as a valid alternative; and indeed the kind of formal/old-fashioned grammar that requires "whom" would probably object to the trailing preposition as well.

Answer (score 4):

I think there's a few things going on here...

> Whom's that book by?

The **contraction** "whom's" sounds odd, because "whom" is now generally used in formal contexts, and contracted "is" in informal contexts.

> Whom is that book by?

Next, the **word order** makes it hard to see which is the subject and object in the sentence. If we switch that around, it becomes clearer that the subject of "is" is "that book":

> That book is by whom?

As [Teaspoon's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/315020/9488) points out, you can usually substitute "he" for "who" and "him" for "whom". In this case we could answer the question like this:

> That book is by him.

This suggests that "whom" is indeed correct. But what about the word order? Let's compare a different phrasing:

> The book is by which person? 
> The book is by that person.

The question is understandable, but doesn't sound natural, because we generally **rearrange the word order to make a question**:

> Which person is the book by? 
> The book is by that person.

(Some grammarians would object that the preposition should not end the sentence, but there is little evidence that natural English has ever followed such a rule.)

Put together, that suggests that the **technically correct** form is:

> Whom is that book by?

However, as others have noted, the use of "whom" in English is declining, so in an **informal** context, as implied by the contracted form, it would probably be:

> Who's that book by?

Comment: Technically 'Whom is that book by?' But modern native speakers say 'Who is that book by?' I guess this may or would cause, in the future, 'by+subjective case' to be widely used: by who

Answer (score 2):

Only *whom* was accepted as correct *when it was the object of the verb.* ("Whom were you speaking to?")

Here, *who* is the subject ("Who is the author of the book?"). It would never have been correct to use *whom* in this context.

Comment: 'whom' is the object of the preposition 'to' and 'who' is a complement and 'the author' is a subject. 'who' is an interrogative pronoun. See this: Who are they? Who is he? and see this: Who made this box?(here who is a subject that made this box)

Comment: Precisely - nobody would ever have said _Whom is he?_ etc.

Comment: I'm a little confused, because "Who is the author of the book?" is not mentioned anywhere in the question (in fact, the word "author" isn't mentioned anywhere in the question), and I don't see any changes in the edit history. I guess that I'm missing something.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan - Sorry, I just paraphrased the sentence to demonstrate that this 'who' refers to someone doing something and not having it done to them.

Comment: But in the question "Who's that book by," the subject is "that book," and the word "who" is the argument of the preposition "by," not the subject.

Comment: @KateBunting Oh I see, but I agree with TS. In OP's sentence the book is "by" (i.e., written by) a person.

Comment: "Who(m) is it by?" is short for "Who(m) is it written by?", which is the passive voice version of "Who wrote it?" So while the author is in reality performing the action of writing, grammatically, the passive voice makes them an indirect object.